# How to have a label hidden when the app starts

Tags: objective-c, xcode, label, hidden

I need a label to be hidden at app startup. I would just like to know how I would go about doing this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If its in the interface builder, you can simply check the "hidden" box in the properties window.

If not, you should do this in `viewDidLoad` just set

```
label.hidden = YES;
```